# Why is python-pdfkit hanging on printing page with OpenLayers3 content when run with uWSGI and NGINX?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf, uwsgi, openlayers-3

I'm using Django served by uWSGI and NGINX.

- Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit
- Python 3.4
- Django 1.7.4
- uWSGI 1.9.17.1-debian (64bit)
- NGINX 1.4.6
- python-pdfkit 0.5.0
- wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1
- OpenLayers v3.0.0

When I try running pdfkit.from_url(...) to print a map to pdf the request times out.

More specifically it hangs in python's subprocess.py communicate, self._communicate:

```
with _PopenSelector() as selector:
    if self.stdin and input:
        selector.register(self.stdin, selectors.EVENT_WRITE)
    if self.stdout:
        selector.register(self.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
    if self.stderr:
        selector.register(self.stderr, selectors.EVENT_READ)

    while selector.get_map():
       ...
```

selector.get_map() always returns a valid result, ensuring an infinite loop.

If I run this in the Django development server (instead of uWSGI+NGINX) everything runs fine.

in my view:

```
wkhtmltopdfBinLocationString = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
wkhtmltopdfBinLocationBytes = wkhtmltopdfBinLocationString.encode('utf-8')
    #this fixes some leftover python2 assumptions about strings
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=wkhtmltopdfBinLocationBytes)

pdfkit.from_url(reportPdfUrl, reportPdfFile, configuration=config, options={
    'javascript-delay': 1500
})
```

Several places I have seen answers along the line of "set the close-on-exec flag on the socket" solving similar issues.

Is this something I can set from my "from_url" options (wkhtmltopdf does not accept it by that name) or can I configure uWSGI to assume 'close-on-exec'? I have not been able to make either of these work, but maybe I just need help with changing my uWSGI customization file:

```
[uwsgi]
workers = 1
chdir = [...]
plugins = python34
wsgi-file = [...]/wsgi.py
pythonpath = [...]
```

I tried something like

```
close-on-exec = true
```

but that didn't seem to do anything.

NOTE: the wsgi.py file is simple:

```
"""
WSGI config for dst project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "[my_project].settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any thoughts?